# Binding a List<Class> to a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I have a List which contains a few items of this class:

`public class Entry
        {
            public string FileSize;
            public string Name;
            public byte[] Data;
            public UInt64 XXHashFilePath;
            public UInt32 FileDataOffset;
            public UInt32 CompressedSize;
            public UInt32 UncompressedSize;
            public CompressionType TypeOfCompression;
            public UInt64 SHA256;
            public Entry(BinaryReader br)
            {
                XXHashFilePath = br.ReadUInt64();
                FileDataOffset = br.ReadUInt32();
                CompressedSize = br.ReadUInt32();
                UncompressedSize = br.ReadUInt32();
                TypeOfCompression = (CompressionType)br.ReadUInt32();
                SHA256 = br.ReadUInt64();
                FileSize = Functions.SizeSuffix(UncompressedSize);
            }
        }`

I want my ListBox to display XXHashFilePath, TypeOfCompression, FileSize, Name in columns in that specific order.

Comment: Start reading here: [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx). First of all, the members of your class should be public properties, not fields, to support data binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have change your fields to properties (like Clemens proposed). This is also a principle of OOP with c# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229057(v=vs.110).aspx

Furthermore you may want to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is just necessary when properties change their value after an Entry was added to the items collection of a ListBox. If Entry elements are immutable and just added to (and removed from) a ListBox, you won't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
public class EntryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _FileSize;
    public string FileSize
    {
        get
        {
            return _FileSize;
        }
        set
        {
            _FileSize = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

It's also a best practice to use the MVVM pattern. Here is a simple base class that should get you started without using a MVVM-framework.

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion Events

    #region Methods

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Comment: "you have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface if you want to sync your view" is only necessary when properties change their value *after* an Entry was added to the items collection of a ListBox. If Entry elements are immutable and just added to (and removed from) a ListBox, you won't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Clemens good point. Thx for clarification -> I've added your comment to my answer.